# How to increment a class number to switch divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to **switch my divs** (I'm creating a div carousel style) with their **class name**. So I would like to *increment* and *decrement* (to go 'next' and 'previous') the "box'1'" number to switch between them anytime I click on the buttons, which contain the js functions

```
<div class="box1"> ...
</div>
<div class="box2"> ...
</div>
<div class="box3"> ...
</div>
<div class="box4"> ...
</div>
```

I found some fixes on this site but still I wasn't able to use them for my code.
So I tried this :

```
function increase() {
  var a = 1;
  var boxes = document.getElementById("box1");
  boxes.value = a;
  a++;
}

function decrease() {
  var a = 1;
  var boxes = document.getElementById("box1");
  boxes.value = a;
  a--;
}
```

And

```
<input class="buttongray" value="next" onclick="increase()">
<input class="buttonblue" value="back" onclick="decrease()">
```

Comment: Have them all the same class but use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to identify them.

Comment: um, you define `a` so each time it sets it to 1..... it will never increase or decrease.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
let ctr = 0;
// onload fill box 1
box[ctr].style.display = "block";
box[ctr].innerHTML = "Box On " + (ctr+1);

function ctrSwitch(n) {
  // int counter
  ctr += n;

  // counter check max and min
  ctr = (ctr>=box.length)? 0 : (ctr < 0) ? box.length-1: ctr;

  // loop and match active box by counter
  box.forEach((el, i) => {
    /* @param el = box[i] */
    // option 1 (use ternary);
    // box[i].innerHTML = (ctr == i)? `Box On ${ctr+1}` : "...";

    // option 2 (use if else);
    if ( ctr == i ) {
       el.style.display = "block";
       el.innerHTML = `Box On ${ctr+1}`;
    }
    else {
       el.style.display = "none";
       el.innerHTML = `...`;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.box1 {
  background: red;
}
.box2 {
  background: green;
}
.box3 {
  background: blue;
}
.box4 {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1"> ...
</div>
<div class="box box2"> ...
</div>
<div class="box box3"> ...
</div>
<div class="box box4"> ...
</div>
<button onclick="ctrSwitch(-1)">Prev</button>
<button onclick="ctrSwitch(1)">Next</button>
```

Comment: This is working great! But it only display me the name " box box1" with the variable.. I need to display the whole div

Comment: I need to only see 1 div at once, so any time I press next it must shows the div class box2, and hide the others, and when pressing prev, it display the box1 and hide the others (with this example)

Comment: see update my answer, or you can 
 visit and learn in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp